# How to properly use page-break property in css

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a HTML page that contains several angular material cards:

```
...

<mat-card class="mat-card-98">

    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>THIS IS MY TITLE</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>

    <mat-card-content>
      THIS IS MY CONTENT
    </mat-card-content>

</mat-card>

...
```

I'm converting this page into a PDF file using the HTML2PDF library, but whenever there is a new page in my pdf the content inside the  gets cut out into half.

Is there a way to use CSS page brakes in order to prevent this behavior? Instead of cutting the content, it should go to a new page and render the content there.

This is what I have tried but it doesn't seem to work:

```
.mat-card {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  break-before: avoid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the css file, try using `page-break-before: always;` if you want that class to be rendered at the top of a pdf page.

Or use `page-break-after : always` if you want nothing to be rendered under that class in the same page.

Lastly, try `page-break-inside: avoid` to avoid breaks inbetween